# How do I print extremely small double precision numbers with fixed format in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

Is there a way to print extremely small double precision numbers **with fixed format** in Fortran?  Somehow, the "E" gets truncated.

Changing the 'ES15' to 'ES18' in the code below doesn't help:

```
program print_double
  implicit none
  double precision :: x
  x = 2.71818D-200
  write(*,*)                 "fmt=*     : x = ", x
  write(*,fmt='(A,ES15.3)') " fmt=ES15.3: x = ", x
  write(*,fmt='(A,E15.3)')  " fmt= E15.3: x = ", x
end program print_double
```

Here's the output:

```
$ gfortran print_double.f90 -o print_double && ./print_double
 fmt=*     : x =    2.7181800000000000E-200
 fmt=ES15.3: x =       2.718-200
 fmt= E15.3: x =       0.272-199

$ ifort print_double.f90 -o print_double && ./print_double
 fmt=*     : x =   2.718180000000000E-200
 fmt=ES15.3: x =       2.718-200
 fmt= E15.3: x =       0.272-199
```

Note: this is for a code in which I check that the solution obtained through two different mathematical approaches agree. Most of the the time, the differences are small (i.e. well below machine precision), but this may not always be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the number of digits in the exponent using the `Ew.dEe` descriptor. It also works for Scientific and Engineering formats.

`write(*,fmt='(A,ES15.3E3)') " fmt=ES15.3E3: x = ", x`

gives

`fmt=ES15.3E3: x =      2.718E-200`

Answer (score 2):

The default width for the magnitude of the exponent field, in the absence of a specification otherwise, is two.  The `E` or `D` exponent letter is dropped if the exponent magnitude needs one character more than provided by the exponent field.  (Note that this form, with the missing exponent letter, is perfectly acceptable for Fortran formatted input.)

If you want three character exponents, then specify three character exponents.

```
write(*,fmt='(A,ES15.3E3)') " fmt=ES15.3E3: x = ", x
write(*,fmt='(A,E15.3E3)')  " fmt= E15.3E3: x = ", x
```