# Python float conversion from incomplete Fortran sci-notation

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, fortran

### The problem

I am producing data files with Fortran 90 program and then analyzing it with Python 3.7. The data files are just many numbers, written in scientific notation.
My problem is that at some point the scientific notation inside files is wrong. The E just disappears. See an example from the **Fortran output** :

```
...
0.2693606328922176223E+99
0.3769504465049542893E+99
0.5275144982939579450E+99
0.7382178439909821718E+99
0.1033081719932198510+100
0.1445722084267474381+100
0.2023182004494124187+100
...
Infinity
Infinity
Infinity
...
```

This leads to the following error on my **Python** analysis program

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.1383817626772070210+100'
```

### Kind of solution I'm looking for

I suppose this problem is inherent to Fortran. I am looking for a Python solution that could handle this weird notation, or at least way to just skip those files that may give weird results after all.

### Program sample

I give you a little sample from my **Python** code, this may help. The following code opens a file, reads a column, and load the whole column inside the PMvar. The for loop is here because I read many files.

```
for rf in range(elem_2):
    # load fluorescence and Temperature
    PMvar[tr] = some_function(filepath[rf])[0]
```

The `some_function` takes as a parameter `filepath[rf]` which is the file path. I only retrieve the first column thus the `[0]` .

```
def some_function(filepath):
    out0 = loadtxt('{}.dat'.format(filepath),comments='%')
    out1 = loadtxt('{}.dat'.format(filepath),comments='%')
    return out0, out1
```

I can't see any explicit conversions from string to float.

Is there a way to adapt this code in order to handle the weird scientific notation ? Or should I just rewrite some stuff to comply with this case ?

### EDIT 1

The Fortran code is not from me, but I think I found where the data is saved.

```
    open(10, file = trim(adjustl(str_file_Temp))//'.dat', status='replace', access='sequential', action='write')
    print*, 'j_save_temp Temp',j_save_temp
        do i = 1, j_save_temp

            write(10,221) save_temperature(i,0),&
                          m_kb_x_inv_n_ions2(1)*save_temperature(i,1:3), &
                          m_kb_x_inv_n_ions(1) *save_temperature(i,4:6), &
                          save_temperature(i,7)/real(n_dt)

        enddo

221     format( 8(1X,e26.19))
    close(10)

    deallocate(save_temperature)
```

with `double precision, allocatable, dimension(:,:) ::  save_temperature`

Comment: "My problem is that at some point the scientific notation inside files is wrong."  Well, the output is probably correct given what the program was asked to print.  Are you interested in modifying your Fortran program to ensure that it has an `e` even with three exponent digits?

Comment: I added the code where (I think) the file is written, check EDIT 1.

Comment: Format like `e26.19` would indeed be the problem.  To change that you can using something like `e27.19e3` (see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33949616/3157076), for example).  Changing the data file (either through modifying the Fortran code that writes it, or by post-processing) is likely to be the easiest solution, but I'm sure you can handle that with Python input if you are desperate.

Comment: By the way, those high values are unphysical temperatures, so I'm more interested in throwing those files. But If you have any comment on the Fortran code about formatting, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: The thing is that those data comes from simulations with very long run time (weeks) so that's why I was interested by handling them whatsoever. I found a way to do this with a ```try:``` instruction on Python, should be able to do this properly. But anyway I will also update the Fortran code for versatility purposes.Thank you.

Comment: This looks like a problem crying out for a quick run through the file with `sed` to 'normalise' the numbers into a form Python can read.  I guess you might even knock up a Python script to do the normalisation.